# Fancy headings with newgeometry

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, geometry

I'm working on a document consisting of several pages of text and a series of full-page figures. Since the figures are larger than the normal text width, I've used the `geometry` package's `\newgeometry` command to change the margins on the pages they're on. So far, so good.

The problem arises when I try to give the document fancy headers and footers with the `fancyhdr` package. My fancy page styles (unlike LaTeX's default page styles) don't adjust to the `\newgeometry`: the header moves to respect the new left margin, but doesn't change its width to reach the right margin.

The following example should show what I mean. The first page, with a fancy page style but no `\newgeometry` is fine. The second page invokes `\newgeometry` and the fancy page style has not adjusted. The third page has the same `\newgeometry` but uses a non-fancy page style; note that the header in this case does extend all the way to the right margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{Fancy page style}    \chead{}            \rhead{}
    \lfoot{}                    \cfoot{}            \rfoot{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\clearpage

\newgeometry{left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}
\lipsum[1-5]
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{headings}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

I've tried everything I can think of, including defining my fancy page style after the `\newgeometry` declaration, but the behaviour is still the same. Is there any way I can put fancy headers on a page with altered margins?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A fix is using `\fancyhfoffset` after `\newgeometry`, so the widths are recalculated, such as

```
\newgeometry{left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}
\fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}
```

After I added `\fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}` to your code, both header and footer are adjusted to the new margin.

Comment: Thank you so much.